# LDA - Why differents formulas to calculate the covariance and the pooled covariance matrix

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, covariance, lda

Reading materials from differents sites some questions have risen about covariance and the pooled covariance matrix calculation to implement LDA:
**Definitions**
Ci - covariance matrix of group i  (C1 and C2)
C  - pooled covariance matrix
u  - global mean (dataset)
ui - mean fo group i   (u1 and u2)
N  - number of samples
Ni - number of group i's samples  (N1 and N2)
Xi - feature i  (X1 and X2)

**1 – Some sites use this formula**

```
C1 = ((x1 – u)T(x1 – u) ) / N1    
C2 = ((x2 – u)T(x2 – u) ) / N2    
C =  (N1/N)C1 + (N2/N)C2
```

**2 – Others use this formula**

```
C1 = ((x1 – u1)T(x1 – u1) ) / N         (can be N or N – K, where K is the number of groups)    
C2 = ((x2 – u2)T(x2 – u2) ) / N         (can be N or N – K)    
C =  (1/N)(C1 + C2 )                    (N or N – K)
```

Why the difference
  in Ci calculus, using global mean or group mean?
  in C calculus, using (1/N) or (Ni/N)?

**Observation:**
In my 4 datasets,
LDA and LDA with quadratic kernel
If I use `((xi – ui)T(xi – ui) ) / N   or ((xi – u)T(xi – u) ) / Ni`  the result is the same

But in QDA
If I use `((xi – u)T(xi – u) ) / Ni` the result (classification) is poorer
than `((xi – ui)T(xi – ui) ) / N`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about stats (try http://stats.stackexchange.com).